# admob ad not showing up in emulator in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, admob

i was following this tutorial here http://www.geojorgx.com/programacion/admob-the-easy-way/ the only thing i tried differently was initing the ad unit id in the main activity which changed nothing. i tried both test and real ad unit ids.\
any help would be awesome.
Xamal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="GOOGLEAD.MainPage"
             xmlns:ads1="clr-namespace:GOOGLEAD.Control">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gainsboro">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                <ads1:AdMobView/>

            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>



    </ContentPage.Content>


</ContentPage>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.googlead" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="GOOGLEAD.Android">
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-5184019642309342~9928782520" />

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

abstraction layer i believe

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace GOOGLEAD.Control
{
    public class AdMobView : ContentView
    {
        public AdMobView() { }
    }
}
```

android

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using GOOGLEAD.Control;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using static GOOGLEAD.Droid.AdMobViewAndroid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdMobView), typeof(AdMobRenderer))]
namespace GOOGLEAD.Droid
{

    class AdMobViewAndroid
    {


        public class AdMobRenderer : ViewRenderer
        {
            public AdMobRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
            {

            }
            private int GetSmartBannerDpHeight()
            {
                var dpHeight = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
                if (dpHeight <= 400) return 32;
                if (dpHeight <= 720) return 50;
                return 90;
            }

            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);

                if (Control == null)
                {
                    var ad = new AdView(Context)
                    {
                        AdSize = AdSize.SmartBanner,
                        AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-5184019642309342/2311352233"
                    };

                    var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

                    ad.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
                    e.NewElement.HeightRequest = GetSmartBannerDpHeight();

                    SetNativeControl(ad);

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Mainactivity

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using GOOGLEAD.Control;


namespace GOOGLEAD.Droid
{

    [Activity(Label = "GOOGLEAD", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "ca-app-pub-5184019642309342/2311352233");
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

the emulator=>[image: theemualtor]

Comment: You may need to set a `HeightRequest="90"` to have it show up!

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT does it have to be 90 because i tried height request and also vertical options center and expand with horizontal center a filll

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT i tried `<ads1:AdMobView HeightRequest="90"/>` and still blank like emulator above.

Comment: Your code looks fine, have you try to clean your project,delete the `obj/bin` file and restart it ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT just tried still didnt work. and yeah i copy and pasted the direct from my project idk why its not working

Comment: What do the logs say?